# No value at JSON path during webTestClient entity creation test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-test

**"Fixed"**:
My endpoint was returning void instead of the User so it couldn't get the values.

I'm making tests using webTestClient for my application and the POST test has no value at JSON.

Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class UserResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        User user = new User(1L, "Slavik", 19);

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/api/user/")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(Mono.just(user), User.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.id").isNotEmpty()
                .jsonPath("$.username").isEqualTo("Slavik");
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllOkForGetAll() {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api/user/")
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBodyList(User.class);
    }
}
```

The GET method works.

Removing the both JSON lines makes the test pass.

.expectBody(User.class) does not work.

Expecting status OK is correct for my case (should be Create but it's not the issue)

Removing $. also did not work

The Endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void add() {
        this.userService.add();
    }
```

User class:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Integer age;
}
```